# iOS State preservation and restoration when data shared between view controllers

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, state-restoration

I'm implementing iOS state preservation and restoration for the first time, so this question may seem obvious to the more experienced!

I have a storyboard with multiple paths to various scenes. For example, from starting scene A the user can go to scene B and then scene C, or the user can go directly to scene C.

A "large" NSDictionary is created in View Controller A which is then passed to View Controller B and subsequently passed to View Controller C (or passed directly to C) via prepareForSegue methods.

I believe I'll be able to restore the NSDictionary in View Controller A, but how do I obtain it for View Controller B and/or C instead making additional copies?

Comment: How many key/values do you have in your dictionary?

Comment: Check out `NSUserDefaults` or the singleton pattern, then the `NSCoding` protocol. As your application's logic grows from managing it's state in a dictionary, you'll want to probably keep state in a custom object or a singleton class. If the former you can write that object to disk, or to `NSUserDefaults` to be extracted as you need it. If you go with the singleton approach you'll have that instance in memory for use whenever you need it. Anyway, there are lots of approaches for managing state as it grows in complexity.

Comment: The NSDictionary is very large and complex. While I could just create multiple copies, I'm interested to know how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the view controllers are restored in order, starting with the root, I found it's actually pretty simple to do what I asked. First, get the index of the current view controller in the Navigation controller. From that, figure out which view controller came before. (If my Storyboard was more complex, I could have used "isKindOfClass" on the previous view controller to determine how to get the NSDictionary in it.)

For example:

```
- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];

    // get current index of views in navigation controller
    int index = [[self navigationController].viewControllers indexOfObject:self];

    if (index == 1) {
        ViewControllerA *view = [[self navigationController].viewControllers objectAtIndex:index - 1];
        self.dict = view.someDict;
    }
    else if (index == 2) {
        ViewControllerB *view = [[self navigationController].viewControllers objectAtIndex:index - 1];
        self.dict = view.arrayOfDict[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There should have no concerns about memory in here. Let's say it looks like this:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue .... {
  nextViewController.dictionary = self.dictionary;    
}
```

I avoided details but the main point is that this is passing a reference to an NSDictionary, not copying the entire dictionary. It means that all your view controllers will in fact share the exact same dictionary.

So their should'nt have any concern about having copies of a large dictionary. Though you should be aware that if View Controller B doesi alter the dictionary, those changes will be affected in every other view controllers.

hope this answers.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is happening. So within nextViewController's decodeRestorableStateWithCoder: method, is it possible to obtain the (already restored) NSDictionary from the previous view controller?

Comment: but the decodeRestorableState should happen only when restoring an app who's memory has been freed. no? You should not encode/decode everytime you perform a segue to a different viewController

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But if my app needs to be restored (e.g., system terminated), I'm trying to restore my view controller's data that was saved with encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:. Since iOS calls this delegate method for each view controller in my Storyboard with a restoration ID (in order), I would like View Controller B to reference the NSDictionary (just restored) in view controller A. Does that make sense?